# SwiftUI LazyVGrid not displaying full height

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to build a view in SwiftUI that displays four equals width columns of squares in full height. Currently everything works, but I don't get the cells displaying in full height.

```
struct FullHeightVGrid: View {
    var columns: [GridItem] = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            ForEach(1..<17) {
              EmptySquare()
            }
        }.frame(
            minWidth: 0,
            maxWidth: .infinity,
            minHeight: 0,
            maxHeight: .infinity
        )
    }
}

struct EmptySquare : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Text("")
            Text("+")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            Text("")
        }
        .frame(
            minWidth: 0,
            maxWidth: .infinity,
            minHeight: 0,
            maxHeight: .infinity
        )
        .padding()
        .background(Color(.systemGray4))
        .cornerRadius(8)
    }
}
```

It looks like this:
[image: LazyVGrid not rendering in full height]

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to force the LazyVGrid to be the height of the whole view, with each grid square being the same height?

Comment: I've adjusted the provided code samples. I guess yes, each `EmptySquare` view should take the available width and height.

Comment: Okay, the simple answer to your question is that a LazyVGrid only takes the height per row of the tallest view in the row, i.e., the row height is dependent upon the height of its tallest view. This makes sense when you think of its intended purpose. So, to handle the height, I would probably use a `GeometryReader` and divide the height by the rows you need plus spacing, and pass that to the view enclosed in the `LazyVGrid`.

Comment: Okay, sounds legit. Would you have an example for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something as simple as this:

```
struct FullHeightVGrid: View {
    var columns: [GridItem] = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        // Read the size here
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            // I removed the spacing to simplify the calculations
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(1..<17) {_ in
                    // divide total height by # of rows.
                    SquareView(height: geometry.size.height / 4)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SquareView: View {
    
    let height: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Full height")
            .padding()
            // Make this view size up to the needed height
            .frame(height: height)
            .background(.gray)
            .border(.black)
            .clipped()
    }
}
```